# helm prometheus-operator not getting custom metrics from api

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I'm using the helm prometheus-operator chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml and I expected it to get my custom metrics from my golang api as I did previously by "hardcoding" the name of the service and the port in the values.yml file:

```js
 scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'custom-api'
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['custom-api-service.backend.svc.cluster.local:8000']
```

However, as I have more microservices I know that it can also be done dynamically using the `_meta` tags. Example: 
`__meta_kubernetes_service_name`

However, I haven't figure it out what should I modify from the values.yaml file to make it work.

Grafana is getting my cpu and memory usage from the `custom-api` but `custom-api` is not appearing in the targets tab from the prometheus dashboard which is weird...

These are my services:

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-api-service
  namespace: backend
  labels:
    service: custom-api-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30080
      protocol: TCP
      name: custom-api
  selector:
    component: goapi

---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: servicemonitor
  namespace: backend
  labels:
    service: servicemonitor
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: custom-api-service
  endpoints:
  - port: custom-api
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a [Service monitor CRD](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md#servicemonitor) to scrape your metrics.

Let's say you have a k8s service (here: `example-app`) which is used to communicate with your microservices. Make sure that your microservice exposes Prometheus metrics at a certain port and the k8s service also includes that port (here: `prom`).

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    app: example-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-app
  ports:
  - name: prom
    port: 8080
  - name: other-port
    port: xxxx
```

This Service object is discovered by a ServiceMonitor, which selects in the same way. You need to make sure that the `matchLabels` of serviceMonitor object matchs the `metadata.labels` of the service.

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    team: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  endpoints:
  - port: prom
```

Once you have created the serviceMonitor object, the operator controller will do the rest for you (ie. update the Prometheus configuration). You can also provide custom configuration via serviceMonitor object.

For more details visit [Getting started with Prometheus operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/getting-started.md#related-resources).
[image: service monitor]

Comment: they are in different namespaces. Helm prometheus-operator is inside monitoring namespace and my `custom-api` is inside the backend namespace how can I configure your  `ServiceMonitor ` accordingly?

Comment: I updated my question with my current service monitor configuration @KamolHasan

Comment: @alex you can use the `namespaceSelector` on the [ServiceMonitor resource CRD](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md#servicemonitor) to specify the namespace. In my case I wanted it to pick up all namespaces so I just set to `any`.
`
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    any: true
`

I also found it important to check the `Prometheus` CRD. For me it had the following
`
serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus-stack
`
which meant I had to have a `prometheus-stack` release label for my CRD

Answer (score 1):

The `Prometheus` resource includes a field called `serviceMonitorSelector`, which defines a selection of `ServiceMonitors` to be used. By default and before the version v0.19.0, `ServiceMonitors` must be installed in the same namespace as the Prometheus instance. With the Prometheus Operator v0.19.0 and above, `ServiceMonitors` can be selected outside the Prometheus namespace via the `serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector` field of the `Prometheus` resource

In the monitoring namespace create a `Prometheus` object which selects the `ServiceMonitor` by label `service: servicemonitor`

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  serviceAccountName: <service-account-name>
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      service: servicemonitor
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
  enableAdminAPI: false
```

The `serviceAccountName` you can find out in `monitoring` namespace as `helmreleasename-prometheus-operator-prometheus`

Comment: which one? there are at least 20 configmaps added by default in that namespace when I install the chart

Comment: can you add it in the values.yaml file

Comment: it didn't work and the answer should have been the same as this other thread but it didn't work either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706343/prometheus-operator-enable-monitoring-for-everything-in-all-namespaces

Comment: create a Prometheus object as in the answer