# How to configure kube-prometheus-stack helm installation to scrape a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I have installed kube-prometheus-stack as a **dependency** in my helm chart on a local docker for Mac Kubernetes cluster v1.19.7. I can view the default prometheus targets provided by the kube-prometheus-stack.

I have a python flask service that provides metrics which I can view successfully in the kubernetes cluster using `kubectl port forward`.

However, I am unable to get these metrics displayed on the prometheus targets web interface.

The [kube-prometheus-stack](https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack#!) documentation states that Prometheus.io/scrape does not support annotation-based discovery of services. Instead the the reader is referred to the concept of `ServiceMonitors` and `PodMonitors`.

So, I have configured my service as follows:

```yaml
---
kind:                       Service
apiVersion:                 v1  
metadata:
  name:                     flask-api-service                    
  labels:
    app:                    flask-api-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol:             TCP 
      port:                 4444
      targetPort:           4444
      name:                 web 
  selector:
    app:                    flask-api-service                    
    tier:                   backend 
  type:                     ClusterIP
---
apiVersion:                 monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind:                       ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name:                     flask-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:                  flask-api-service
  endpoints:
  - port:                   web
```

Subsequently, I have setup a port forward to view the metrics:

```sh
Kubectl port-forward prometheus-flaskapi-kube-prometheus-s-prometheus-0 9090
```

Then visited prometheus web page at `http://localhost:9090`

When I select the Status->Targets menu option, my flask-api-service is not displayed.

I know that the service is up and running and I have checked that I can view the metrics for a pod for my flask-api-service using `kubectl port-forward <pod name> 4444`.

Looking at a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65648944) it looks as though there is a  configuration value `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` that defaults to true. Setting this to false makes the operator look outside it’s release labels in helm??

I tried adding this to the `values.yml` of my helm chart in addition to the `extraScrapeConfigs` configuration value. However, the *flask-api-service* still does not appear as an additional target on the prometheus web page when clicking the Status->Targets menu option.

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
  extraScrapeConfigs: |
    - job_name: 'flaskapi'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['flask-api-service:4444']
```

How do I get my *flask-api-service* recognised on the prometheus targets page at `http://localhost:9090`?

I am installing Kube-Prometheus-Stack as a dependency via my helm chart with default values as shown below:

**Chart.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: "0.0.1"
description: A Helm chart for flaskapi deployment
name: flaskapi
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
- name: kube-prometheus-stack
  version: "14.4.0"
  repository: "https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts"
- name: ingress-nginx
  version: "3.25.0"
  repository: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
- name: redis
  version: "12.9.0"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

**Values.yaml**

```yaml
docker_image_tag: dcs3spp/
hostname: flaskapi-service
redis_host: flaskapi-redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local 
redis_port: "6379"

prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
  extraScrapeConfigs: |
    - job_name: 'flaskapi'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['flask-api-service:4444']
```

Comment: Please share the values.yaml (just the values you override) file you used to install prometheus via kube-prometheus-stack helm chart.

Comment: Thanks, details added to question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prometheus custom resource definition has a field called `serviceMonitorSelector`. Prometheus only listens to those matched serviceMonitor. In case of helm deployment it is your release name.

```
release: {{ $.Release.Name | quote }}
```

So adding this field in your serviceMonitor  should solve the issue. Then you serviceMonitor manifest file will be:

```
apiVersion:                 monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind:                       ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name:                     flask-api-service
  labels:
      release: <your_helm_realese_name_>
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:                  flask-api-service
  endpoints:
  - port:                   web
```

Comment: Magic, much appreciated, that did the trick. Many thanks!!!! Accepting answer and upvoting :)

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: @PulakKantiBhowmick You must be referring to this field: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1949
Where do you see it's value being the release name by default?

Comment: Please check here
https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml#L109

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of discussion, if the default `matchLabels` is `release: {{ $.Release.Name | quote }}` , do you think the statement here is wrong: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1947

Comment: Seems ok to me. For that user have to set serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: true

Comment: Sorry to heckle you more on this, but did you meant to say `serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` needs to be set to `false` for this statement: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1947
to be true. Only then it would set `serviceMonitorSelector` to {} and select all `ServiceMonitors` as per condition here: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml#L112

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230557/discussion-between-rockn-rolla-and-pulak-kanti-bhowmick).

Comment: In my case 'release' label had to be set not only on ServiceMonitor but on Service level as well.