# Prometheus doesn't discover my pod monitor

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus, strimzi

I want to monitor my Kafka deployed using Strimzi operator. I deployed Prometheus operator alongside a few basic monitoring tools using community chart https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack, then followed Strimzi documentation https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/deploying.html#assembly-metrics-str to configure kafka exporter and other metrics to being exposed. Strimzi examples have pod monitors `cluster-operator-metrics`, `entity-operator-metrics` and `kafka-resources-metrics`. Everything discovered and scrapped successfully except one pod monitor `cluster-operator-metrics` which is even now showed up in Prometheus instance.

[image]

I have following architecture:

- My strimzi operator deployed into `strimzi-system` namespace and watches for namespace `A`
- Kafka brokers, exporters, entity operator deployed into namespace `A`
- Kube prometheus stack chart (with prometheus operator) deployed into `monitoring` namespace
- I have deployed second prometheus instance into namespace `A` to configure different retention and collect metrics in another place. This prometheus instance successfully discovered targets for `entity-operator-metrics` and `kafka-resources-metrics`
- `entity-operator-metrics` and `kafka-resources-metrics` pod monitors deployed to namespace A
- `cluster-operator-metrics` deployed to `strimzi-system` namespace

I want to scrape metrics for `cluster-operator-metrics` deployed in `strimzi-system` namespace by prometheus deployed in `monitoring` namespace.

Here is manifests which I'm using:

**Prometheus** instance deployed to `monitoring` namespace

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-06T10:29:49Z"
  generation: 7
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 45.0.0
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-45.0.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "8888421"
  uid: 4fbc11f6-5547-45de-ad77-40fbd37d5e1d
spec:
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - apiVersion: v2
      name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager
      namespace: monitoring
      pathPrefix: /
      port: http-web
  enableAdminAPI: false
  evaluationInterval: 30s
  externalUrl: http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.monitoring:9090
  hostNetwork: false
  image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.42.0
  listenLocal: false
  logFormat: logfmt
  logLevel: info
  paused: false
  podMonitorNamespaceSelector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: kubernetes.io/metadata.name
      operator: In
      values:
      - monitoring
      - strimzi-system
  podMonitorSelector: {}
  portName: http-web
  probeNamespaceSelector: {}
  probeSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  replicas: 1
  retention: 10d
  routePrefix: /
  ruleNamespaceSelector: {}
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  scrapeInterval: 30s
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      kubernetes.io/metadata.name: monitoring
  serviceMonitorSelector: {}
  shards: 1
  version: v2.42.0
  walCompression: true
```

**Prometheus** instance deployed to namespace `A`

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-06T11:23:09Z"
  generation: 7
  name: kafka-prometheus
  namespace: A
  resourceVersion: "8888395"
  uid: 43ab949d-4b1f-4ad2-843c-5a22e7ecc1a1
spec:
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    key: prometheus-additional.yaml
    name: additional-scrape-configs
  enableAdminAPI: false
  evaluationInterval: 30s
  podMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: strimzi
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
  retention: 30d
  scrapeInterval: 30s
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: kafka-prometheus-server
  serviceMonitorSelector: {}
  storage:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
        storageClassName: standard
```

**PodMonitor** for `entity-operator-metrics` in namespace A

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-06T11:56:15Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: strimzi
  name: kafka-entity-operator-metrics
  namespace: A
  resourceVersion: "4290222"
  uid: f1d14d38-e1ad-404f-94ba-7ff294923608
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - A
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: healthcheck
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: entity-operator
```

**PodMonitor** for `kafka-resource-metrics` in namespace A

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-06T11:56:15Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: strimzi
  name: kafka-resource-metrics
  namespace: A
  resourceVersion: "4290228"
  uid: 48a4e919-51ab-433d-9dbe-8f0352d7341d
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - A
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: tcp-prometheus
    relabelings:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(strimzi_io_.+)
      replacement: $1
      separator: ;
    - action: replace
      regex: (.*)
      replacement: $1
      separator: ;
      sourceLabels:
      - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
      targetLabel: namespace
    - action: replace
      regex: (.*)
      replacement: $1
      separator: ;
      sourceLabels:
      - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
      targetLabel: kubernetes_pod_name
    - action: replace
      regex: (.*)
      replacement: $1
      separator: ;
      sourceLabels:
      - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
      targetLabel: node_name
    - action: replace
      regex: (.*)
      replacement: $1
      separator: ;
      sourceLabels:
      - __meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip
      targetLabel: node_ip
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: strimzi.io/kind
      operator: In
      values:
      - Kafka
      - KafkaConnect
```

**PodMonitor** for `cluster-operator-metrics` in namespace `strimzi-system`

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-12T14:30:33Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: strimzi
  name: kafka-cluster-operator-metrics
  namespace: strimzi-system
  resourceVersion: "8255294"
  uid: 0986ba6a-dc83-4000-91b4-efc6f16462e4
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - strimzi-system
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - path: /metrics
    port: healthcheck
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      strimzi.io/kind: cluster-operator
```

What I have tried:

- I have checked, that strimzi cluster operator has target labels `strimzi.io/kind: cluster-operator` and here is a part of pod manifest of strimzi operator

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-01-31T16:22:36Z"
  generateName: strimzi-cluster-operator-77f9c84bc-
  labels:
    name: strimzi-cluster-operator
    pod-template-hash: 77f9c84bc
    strimzi.io/kind: cluster-operator
  name: strimzi-cluster-operator-77f9c84bc-h9895
  namespace: strimzi-system
```

- Also, I have checked that Prometheus service account deployed in `monitoring` has cluster role with permission to access metrics endpoint:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-06T10:29:46Z"
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 45.0.0
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-45.0.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  resourceVersion: "8223589"
  uid: f13d2445-b185-4b75-aa92-ba97b7393da0
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/metrics
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /metrics
  - /metrics/cadvisor
  verbs:
  - get
```

- I verified that strimzi operator pod returns metrics on endpoint `GET /metrics`
- Tried to deploy PodMonitor into `monitoring` and `A` namespace
- Tried to disable any restrictions to discover pod monitors in Prometheus in namespace `monitoring`. It discovered 2 other pod monitors which is worked before, but still didn't find strimzi cluster operator pod monitor. Followed by this answer [prometheus operator - enable monitoring for everything in all namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706343/prometheus-operator-enable-monitoring-for-everything-in-all-namespaces)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706343/prometheus-operator-enable-monitoring-for-everything-in-all-namespaces

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I described it in last statement. But anyway, thanks, I will add this information to initial description

Answer (score 2):

This is an old one, but here goes in case anyone finds it useful. I had some headache with a similar problem. In prometheus-stack's helm values, there's this.

```
## PodMonitors to be selected for target discovery.
## If {}, select all PodMonitors
##
podMonitorSelector: {}
```

*But* then there's also this:

```
## If true, a nil or {} value for prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelector will cause the
## prometheus resource to be created with selectors based on values in the helm deployment,
## which will also match the podmonitors created
##
podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: true
```

Which is true by default. The PodMonitors will be scraped if that is set to false, or kube-prometheus-stack's labels are added to the PodMonitor.

Answer (score 2):

If you, like me, came here because your PodMonitor is not working in microk8s. It is because of the previous answer that

```
## If true, a nil or {} value for prometheus.prometheusSpec.podMonitorSelector will cause the
## prometheus resource to be created with selectors based on values in the helm deployment,
## which will also match the podmonitors created
##
podMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: true
```

This will generate a manifest with the following selector

```
podMonitorSelector:
  matchLabels:
    release: "kube-prom-stack"
```

And because of this you can easily work around this by creating your PodMonitor in any namespace, just give it the helm release label **release: kube-prom-stack**

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  name: my-pod-monitor
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: my-pod-monitor
    release: kube-prom-stack
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/enable-actuator-prometheus: "true"
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - default
  podMetricsEndpoints:
    - port: http-management
      path: '/actuator/prometheus'
```

Comment: I enabled `microk8s.enable observability`.  Where did you find out which helm files are used by this command?