# Why metrics server error? FailedDiscoveryCheck

Tags: kubernetes

There were many similar questions on SO([Kubernetes metrics-server FailedDiscoveryCheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531350/kubernetes-metrics-server-faileddiscoverycheck))

Mine is specific cause I have k3s cluster.

```
kubectl get apiservices
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   False (FailedDiscoveryCheck)   5d2h
```

My nodes

```
NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
k3s-1   Ready    control-plane,master   5d2h   v1.26.2+k3s1
k3s-2   Ready    <none>                 5d2h   v1.26.2+k3s1
k3s-3   Ready    <none>                 5d2h   v1.26.2+k3s1
```

I checked deployment

```
spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=10250
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=15s
```

should I change preferred address-types?